# SQLAlchemy does not recognize manual changes made in external editor

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have noticed that any changes made to my SQLite Database using an **external editor** such as *DB Browser* are not recognized by SQLAlchemy. My use case is, that i need to check and retrieve unique constraints in the table, which works fine with the following code:

`mymodels.py` contains my tables. Consider the following example table:

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = "mytable"
    mytable_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    unique_col = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)
```

`myutils.py` contains a helper function to create sessions.

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager

def get_managed_session_maker(SessionMaker):

    @contextmanager
    def make_managed_session():
        session = SessionMaker()
        try:
            yield session
            session.commit()
        except Exception as e:
            session.rollback()
            raise RuntimeError(e)
        finally:
            session.close()
    
    return make_managed_session
```

`db.py` contains my database logic.

```py
from mymodels import Base
import myutils
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, inspect

class Database():
    def __init__(self, db_uri):
        self.db_uri = db_uri
        self.engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(db_uri)
        Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine) # create tables

        Base.metadata.bind = self.engine
        SessionMaker = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)
        self.ManagedSessionMaker = utils.get_managed_session_maker(SessionMaker)
        metadata = MetaData()
        metadata.reflect(bind=self.engine)
        self.metadata = metadata

    def get_unique_cols(self, table_name: str) -> list[str]:
        ...

        unique_cols = list()

        inspector = inspect(self.engine)
        tmp = inspector.get_unique_constraints(table_name)
        for unique in tmp:
            unique_cols.append(unique.get("column_names")[0])
        return unique_cols
```

In this case, the `get_unique_cols` function would return a list containing `unique_col` as string. However, if i were to manually remove the unique constraint and then manually add it back with an external editor such as DB Browser, then my function returns an empty list, thus  not recognizing the change. Is there any way to recognize manual changes to the SQLite Database in SQLAlchemy?

## Update

So, let me illustrate my problem on a concrete table. I created a `test.py` script to create a new Engine instance and print out unique constraints:

`test.py`

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, inspect

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///mydb.db")
  
inspector = inspect(engine)
uc = inspector.get_unique_constraints("_agegroups_10y")
print(uc)
```

First, i let SQLAlchemy create the table `_agegroups_10y` which looks like this in the DB Browser:

[image]

When i run the script without any manual changes to the table, i get the output as expected:

```bash
$ python test.py 
[{'name': None, 'column_names': ['agegroup']}, {'name': None, 'column_names': ['unique_key']}]
```

Now when i manually delete the unique constraint for `unique_key` (or any other column)...

[image]

... i get an empty list as output.

```bash
$ python test.py 
[]
```

So everytime i manually change the unique constraint, i get an empty list back... This is a weird behavior to me, as i at least expected to get the same output as before. Any idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Exit DB Browser and re-open it. Does it still show that "agegroup" is a unique column? I'm wondering if dropping the unique constraint on "unique_key" is also dropping the unique constraint on "agegroup", possibly because the constraints are not named.

Comment: @GordThompson yes it does. All changes that i do in DB Browser will remain when i re-open it. However, i get an empty list when i try to get the unique constraints (After i changed the constraints in DB Browser) with SQLAlchemy as shown above. Ill try to name the constraints with SQLAlchemy, maybe that works...

Comment: "First, i let SQLAlchemy create the table _agegroups_10y which looks like this in the DB Browser" - I don't get the same result. With SQLAlchemy 1.4.39 under Python 3.10.2 (SQLite version 3.35.5), [this code](https://pastebin.com/TfX8dEhz) produces a table that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpKmn.png). Notice that "U" boxes are not checked and that the columns are subject to `UNIQUE()` constraints.